# How to calculate shipping fee from tuples in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, calculation

I am looking to return the delivery charge in pence (p) for each order. We have a flat £50 (5000p) fee plus £20 (2000p) for each 100lb (additional weight ignored below 100lbs).

An ordered item has 4 components: name, quantity, unit price (in pence), unit weight (in pounds)

```
ORDER_SAMPLE_1 = {("lamp", 2, 2399, 2), ("chair", 4, 3199, 10), ("table", 1, 5599, 85)}
ORDER_SAMPLE_2 = {("sofa", 1, 18399, 140), ("bookshelf", 2, 4799, 40)}


def delivery_charges(order):
    E.g., delivery_charges({("desk", 1, 11999, 160)}) is 7000 (pence)
    E.g., delivery_charges({("desk", 2, 11999, 160)}) is 11000 (pence)
    E.g., delivery_charges({("lamp", 1, 2399, 2)}) is 5000 (pence)
    E.g., delivery_charges({("lamp", 50, 2399, 2)}) is 7000 (pence)
```

Is a for loop or elif the best way to approach?

Comment: how are u calculating `7000 ` from `("desk", 1, 11999, 160)` ?

Comment: Also what does the numbers mean in `("lamp", 2, 2399, 2)`

Comment: An ordered item has four components:
 - a name
 - a quantity (the number of such items bought)
 - a unit price (in pence)
 - a unit weight (in pounds)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that 5000p is the base fee for the whole order and not for each item in it. So here is one way you can do this,

- You can iterate over all the items in an order.
- For each item calculate its total weight then calculate the extra_charges by dividing the total weight by 100 and then multiplying it with 2000.
- Add this to the total charges. Return the total charges after the loop finishes iterating.

```
def delivery_charges(order):
  total_charges = 5000
  for item in order:
    total_item_weight = item[1] * item[3]
    extra_charges = (total_item_weight // 100) * (2000)
    total_charges += extra_charges   
  return total_charges
```